# Conditional For Loops in VBScript

Tags: loops, for-loop, vbscript

I need to create a conditional `For...Next` loop in my VBScript and it needs to have multiple (Here I need five) sub conditions in it whose can control behavior of the loop.

Here is my current code:

```
TOTAL_1 = 1
TOTAL_2 = 2
TOTAL_3 = 3
TOTAL_4 = 4
TOTAL_5 = 5 '<< Those are values of sub "To" conditions

TOTAL = TOTAL_1 + TOTAL_2 + TOTAL_3 + TOTAL_4 + TOTAL_5 '<< Total value of main "To" condition

For I = 1 To TOTAL

  If I = 1 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_1

  If I = 2 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 2"
  If I = 3 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 2" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_2

  If I = 4 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 3"
  If I = 5 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 3"
  If I = 6 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 3" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_3

  If I = 7 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 4"
  If I = 8 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 4"
  If I = 9 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 4"
  If I = 10 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 4" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_4

  If I = 11 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5"
  If I = 12 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5"
  If I = 13 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5"
  If I = 14 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5"
  If I = 15 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_5

Next
```

Although above code works, I need to change For Loop every time I change values of sub conditions like

```
TOTAL_1 = 20, TOTAL_4 = 8
```

This For Loop should execute 15 Times as assigned in variable `TOTAL`, but even value of `I` changes in the loop, it should check what is the sub condition currently `I` belongs to and then do same work (here display a same message) until value of `I` belongs to the next sub condition.

If I change value of sub condition `TOTAL_1` as 5, I need to make the following change in this For Loop:

```
If I = 1 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1"
If I = 2 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1"
If I = 3 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1"
If I = 4 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1"
If I = 5 Then WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1" '<< For changed sub condition TOTAL_1
```

I also need to add more sub conditions like `TOTAL_6`, `TOTAL_7`... in future.

How can I do this without changing for loop every time and how can I remove arbitrary lines from this code, making this more smaller?

Comment: Check into 'select case', as it may help shorten the code for you. See the example near the bottom of this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement

Comment: @PaulT. this is very useful, never mind that loop exists in VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modifying the If conditions as shown below:

```
For I = 1 To TOTAL

  If I <= TOTAL_1 Then 

    WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 1" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_1

  ElseIf I>TOTAL_1 and I<=TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2 Then 

    WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 2"

  ElseIf I>TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2 and I<=TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2+TOTAL_3 Then 

    WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 3" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_3

  ElseIf I>TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2+TOTAL_3 and I<=TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2+TOTAL_3+TOTAL_4 Then 

    WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 4" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_4

  ElseIf I>TOTAL_1+TOTAL_2+TOTAL_3+TOTAL_4 and I<=TOTAL Then 

    WScript.Echo "Currently in Set 5" '<< For sub condition TOTAL_5

  Else

    Wscript.Echo "Not in any set"

  End If

Next
```

You can add further more conditions for TOTAL_6,7 and so on...

Edit 2: To make it even shorter, you can do something like this:

```
arr=Array(1,2,3,4,5)                    'this array contains all your Total_1,2,3,4,5 values. You can add more.
fullSum = func_sum(arr,UBound(arr))(1)    'In this case, the value is 15(sum of all elements)      
For i=0 To UBound(arr)
    sum = func_sum(arr,i)
    For k=1 To fullSum 
        If k>sum(0) And k<=sum(1) Then
            WScript.Echo "Currently in Set "&i+1
        End If
    Next
Next


Function func_sum(intArr, tempPos)      'returns the sums of all elements upto indices tempPos-1 and tempPos
    tempPos2=tempPos-1
    sum1=0
    sum2=0
    If tempPos=0 Then
        sum2=intArr(tempPos)
    Else
        For j=0 To tempPos2
            sum1 = sum1 + arr(j)
        Next
        sum2 = sum1 + arr(tempPos)
    End If
    arrSum = Array(sum1,sum2)
    func_sum=arrSum
End Function
```

In the 2nd Solution, you just need to add more elements to the array and change nothing else.